# Ncurses, non-blocking getch misses first character

Tags: c, linux, nonblocking, ncurses, getch

Im using Linux and ncurses for my application, and i'm using getch as non-blocking using nodelay. The problem is that while looping with getch for the input, it always misses the first character. For example the input "Helloworld" would print up as "elloworld".
I dont seem to see any problems at the moment, though maybe its because i've been staring at the code for far to long, or i've missed something out.

```
    while(TRUE)
{   
    gchar chr;
    gchar *cmd =  g_malloc(50);

    if((getch()) == ERR)
    {
        // no user input
    }
    else
    {
        gint i = 0;

        while((chr = getch()) != '\n')
        {
            cmd[i] = chr;
            waddch(ncurse->window, chr);
            wrefresh(ncurse->window);
            i++;
        }

        waddstr(ncurse->log, cmd);
        wrefresh(ncurse->log);

        wmove(ncurse->window, ncurse->window->_maxy, 2);
        wclrtoeol(ncurse->window);

        wrefresh(ncurse->window);
    }

    g_free(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect?

```
if((getch()) == ERR)
  {
    // no user input
  }
```

discards the first character, if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for a fresh pair of eyes and a push in the right direction, its fixed now.